# By the binomial theorem, use this result to show with explanation that the number of subsets of a set $S$ is $2^{|S|}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Given that $(1+1)^n = 2^n = \sum^n_{k=0} \binom{n}{k}$ by the binomial theorem use this result to show with explanation that the number of subsets of a set $S$ is $2^{|S|}$

I'm really confused.

So using the formula I got

$(1+1)^s = 2^s = \sum^s_{k=0} \binom{s}{k} 1^{s-0} * 1^0$

= $2^s = \sum^s_{k=0} \binom{s}{k}$

but now what? Any help would be great

Comment: This statement is false as it stands, It's true for AT MOST COUNTABLE sets only. Please correct it.

Comment: Yea I have NO idea what you are talking about, you need to be more specific.

Comment: He is saying if your set is infinite, you can't count the subsets either.

Comment: Thank you,Advin. But I actually said more then that-I'm saying this statement only applies if the sets under consideration can be put in one to one correspondence with subsets of N. I don't think the binomial argument works in this concrete form for the reals,for example.

Comment: Your opinion was noted Mathemagician but you are incorrect, my solution is correct and was verified by my professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the following: ${s \choose k}$ is the count of the sub-sets with exactly k elements. 
When you sum these counts you get the count of all sub-sets.
And you just proved that sum is $2^s$.

Comment: Yes but how do I get that $S$ in the exponential to be $|S|$?

Comment: You don't get it, you assume it. You say let s = |S|. Then we notice that: $(1+1)^s = ... $ and so on ...

Comment: so my answer is correct then?  I just need to change $2^{S}$ to $2^{|S|}$?

Comment: Sure, it's correct. You can say in the beginning: let n=|S|. Then rewrite your formulas with n instead of S. It will be much cleaner. But the result will be the same. You have proved it, you just have to add a few English words here and there :) Replace s with n in my answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

The number of subsets is $2^S$ because, you either choose an element to be part of it or not, and you do this $S$ times, with each element: $2*... * 2$ (S times) = $2^S$. Multilpying can be done, since you do them independently.

Comment: You don't even need the binomial theorem for that :)